# Append ordinal suffixes ('-st', '-nd', '-rd', '-th') based on the item index

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Say, I have an array of option values, like:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
```

And I need to translate that into array of formatted strings, like:

```
var result = ['1-st option is "a"', '2-nd option is "b", '3-rd option is "c"', '4-th option is "d"',...];
```

I managed to achieve most part of it with:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result.push((i+1)+' option is "'+arr[i]+'"');
}
```

It produces the strings, like `1 option is "a"`, so on.
But I can't seem to cope with those suffixes ('-st', '-nd', '-rd', '-th'). Would you, guys, help me out with the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put necessary suffixes into array and pick the one that corresponds to your index:

```js
const arr = [...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
const suffixes = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];

const result = arr.map((item, i) => 
  (idx = ~~(i % 10) + 1 > 3 || ~~(i / 10) == 1 ? 0 : ~~(i % 10) + 1, 
  `${i+1}-${suffixes[idx]} options is '${item}'`));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-width: 100%}
```

Comment: Tested this in an array over 100 items long. Good answer.

Comment: I accept your answer because it was the first to provide desired output. Now that @Ghoul Ahmed has edited his post it seems also compact and efficient, I could've upvoted that but my reputation record is not enough for that privilege :(

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg, your solution is fastest, so I upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try this Code it works :**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator#English

-st is used with numbers ending in 1 (e.g. 1st, pronounced first)

-nd is used with numbers ending in 2 (e.g. 92nd, pronounced ninety-second)

-rd is used with numbers ending in 3 (e.g. 33rd, pronounced thirty-third)

As an exception to the above rules, all the "teen" numbers ending with 11, 12 or 13 use -th (e.g. 11th, pronounced eleventh, 112th, pronounced one hundred [and] twelfth)

-th is used for all other numbers (e.g. 9th, pronounced ninth).

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function addSuffix(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "-st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "-nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "-rd";
    }
    return i + "-th";
}

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(`${addSuffix(i + 1)} option is  '${arr[i]}'`);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please describe, how will this snippet answer the question, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
const  arr= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

const ordinal_suffix_of = (n) => (["st","nd","rd"][((n+90)%100-10)%10-1] || "th")

const result  = arr.map((res,i)=> `${i+1}-${ordinal_suffix_of(i+1)} option is '${res}'`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: all your result is `-st`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Read, what's the OP asking for

Comment: @GhoulAhmed : I like current edit of your post, so I upvote it, even though it still seems a bit [slower](https://jsperf.com/ljkasdoiuoi/1) than mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function  with modulo `%` that handles that for you, for instance:

```
function calc_suffix(number) {
    let rest = number % 10;

    if(rest === 1 && number != 11) { return 'st'; }
    else if(rest === 2 && number != 12) { return 'nd'; }
    else if(rest === 3 && number != 13) { return 'rd'; }
    else { return 'th'; }
}
```

The end result would look like:

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result.push((i+1) + "-" + calc_suffix(i+1) + " option is "'+arr[i]+'"');
}
```